# How do I equip more moves?

Tags: absolver

Currently, I can only equip two moves for the up/right and up/left stances, and one move each for the down/right and down/left stances, plus one extra move per stance on the other button.

I've seen people with decks that have three moves per stance, though. How do I unlock bigger decks so that I can actually start customizing things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From personal experience, you gain more slots in your combat deck stances as you level up. There is nothing special you need to do.

For instance, I unlocked the second slot in the bottom left and bottom right stances when I reached level 12 and then unlocked the third slot for the top left and right stances at level 18.

Comment: Interesting. I have unlocked some since I asked the question but I still wasn't sure what the trigger was, because I always did it after killing one of the marked enemies. I'll see what level I am when I get a chance to play again to see if it aligns with your answer.

Comment: I *believe* I unlocked the slots after actually spending the skill points to level up, but I can double check tonight. Since my save got corrupted when the game crashed, I'll just pay extra close attention to what happens when I hit level 12 (again :( )

Comment: @StrixVaria also, for reference, it's not really elaborated on, but in [this FAQ by the devs](https://steamcommunity.com/app/473690/discussions/0/2579854400733819593/), they seemed to hint that level determines combat deck slots: "Additional slots will be progressively unlocked in the Combat Deck, **allowing high level players to create more complex choreographies**."